# MeteorJS: Using elasticsearch with easy:search package

Tags: javascript, meteor, elasticsearch, meteor-easy-search

Noob here, trying to set up easy:search to use elasticsearch as its engine. How do I go about it? What I have so far doesn't seem to work.

```
ArtistsIndex = new Index({
    collection: Artists,
    fields: ['name'],
    engine: new ElasticSearchEngine({
        query: function () {
           // what goes in here???
        }
   })
});
```

I believe I ought to configure a query as one of the options in the engine, but I can't seem to get that part right.

Comment: Can you follow this once https://www.sitepoint.com/search-engine-node-elasticsearch/ ?

Comment: @kawadhiya21, I've tried to follow the article but I'm not sure how to integrate it into easy:search. All that I've tried is resulting in errors.